# Excel predefined format accident

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

Hi everyone I have a serious problem with my spreadsheet (xlsm)

I don't know how, but cells with default format were converted to currency $, for example C12 has 123, now is $123.00.

How I can change this disaster? This problems happens in all of my sheets. Please tell me something.

Comment: you want $123 or 123.

Comment: XSLM is a macro-enabled workbook.  Do you have code that runs each time which could be changing the format?  Did you possibly play with the [default template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-how-excel-starts-HP005199391.aspx)?

Comment: I want 123. I have a lot of code, and I have a lot of sheets, day to night all my book were corrupted. Rare problem. But to my relief There was a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried right clicking on C12 then Format cells. 
if this worked then select whole sheet and do same.

[image]

Comment: but I have many formats in mi sheet, day to night all my book were corrupted, predefined style were signed as currency cell. To my relief, I had saved a backup. Thanks all.

Comment: Good you did that, but you will face same problem again with the same code.

Comment: It's not about my code, My book is used by seven guys (1year) and nothing happens. Whatever, I was an accident. Thanks.